New Relic Browser Monitoring error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"
I am using browser agent for my NextJS application. I have integrated it using APM.
I am getting this error very frequently:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length').

I am attaching the screenshot of my sentry issue for reference.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have used APM for browser monitoring.
